# Why doesn't the value come to the method via AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application, code in `Index.cshtml`:

```
<button onclick="Get()">Send</button>

<script>
    function Get(){
         var results = new Array();

         var emp1 = { "ID": "12", "Name": "Manas" };
         var emp2 = { "ID": "2", "Name": "Tester" };
         results.push(emp1);
         results.push(emp2);

         console.log(results);

         $.ajax({
             url: 'Home/GetQuiz',
             data: JSON.stringify(results),
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: "application/json",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (resp) {
                 //request sent and response received.
             }
         });
    }
</script>
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetQuiz(List<Employee> empList)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

I get into the action of the controller, but the list is empty, please tell me why?

In the layout page, the link to the library is connected:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are using  "application/json" content type, you should use frombody attribute in your action, and redirect is not working when ajax is used, try just to return action

```
public IActionResult GetQuiz([FromBody] List<Employee> empList)
{
return Index();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since your content type is "application/json", use the `[FromBody]` attribute in the controller action method. Read more [on Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And since you are on the Home controller already, you do not need to redirect to action, just return the index.

```cs
public IActionResult GetQuiz([FromBody] List<Employee> empList)
{
   return Index();
}
```